# How to initialize a named volume shared across several containers with docker-compose

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

I'm trying to build my own wordpress-nginx-php_fpm stack with docker-compose but I face a problem with named-volume and its initialization.

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:

  db: #https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/
    image: mysql                                                                       
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "wp-db:/var/lib/mysql:rw"
      - env_file:
      - "./conf/db/mysql.env"
    networks:
      - back                                                                          

  nginx: #https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "wp-files:/usr/share/nginx/html"
      - "./conf/nginx:/nginx:ro"
      - "./conf/tools:/tools:ro"
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    environment:
      - "PHP_FPM_HOST=php-wp:9000"
      - "PHP_FPM_ROOT_DIR=/var/www/html"
    command: "bash /tools/wait-for-it.sh php-wp:9000 -t 30 -- bash /tools/detemplatize-it.sh /nginx/nginx.template:/nginx.conf -- nginx -c /nginx.conf"

  php-wp: #https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/
    image: "wordpress:fpm"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - "wp-files:/var/www/html"
      - "./conf/tools:/tools:ro"
    env_file:
      - "conf/wp/wordpress.env"
    networks:
      - back
    command: "bash /tools/wait-for-it.sh db:3306 -t 30 -- php-fpm -F"

networks:
  front: {}
  back: {}

volumes:
  wp-files: {}
  wp-db: {}
```

As you can see, I have 2 named volumes. No problem with "wp-db" because it's used only with the "db" service.

My problem is with the "wp-files" volume, mounted in 2 services(=containers)

- Which service will copy its data to the named volume first ?
- Does the second container will overwrite the data put by the first one ?
- How to "initialize" the named volume somewhere and just use it (after) the 2 containers where its mounted ? I heard about a "nocopy" flag.
- Am I obliged to use other stuff (like data container) instead of named volume ?

Thank you.
Note: (everything is on the same physical host)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I could find as an answer:

> Which service will copy its data to the named volume first ?

The container that starts first (thanks to volumes-from, depends-on, ...)

> Does the second container will overwrite the data put by the first one?

No, once a named volume has been "initialized" (means no empty anymore), it will overwrite every mount point where it 's attached to.

> How to "initialize" the named volume somewhere and just use it (after)
>   the 2 containers where its mounted ? I heard about a "nocopy" flag.

There is indeed a "nocopy" flag, like in the "docker run" documentation, BUT doesn't seem to work with other flag ("ro" or "rw").

> Am I obliged to use other stuff (like data container) instead of named
>   volume ?

Therefore, no.

Comment: You can use 'nocopy', with other flags like "ro" and "rw", but you have to separate them with "," instead of ":".  For example, 'tesstvol:/test:ro,nocopy'